# Interactive variation of integration limit

Tags: numerical-integration, manipulate

I want to compute this function for different values of `Kappa`, so that I don't have to change `Kappa` manually. Some kind of `Manipulate` expression.

```
Integralfunc[t_] :=  
  NIntegrate[a^-2(Exp[-1/a^2]*BesselI[0, 1/a^2], {a, 0. 02, Kappa*t}]
SetAttributes[Integralfunc, Listable]
DeFunc = IntegralFunc[Range[0.1, 250, 1.25]]
ListPlot[DeFunc, PlotStyle Red]
```

Comment: Why not just `Integralfunc[t_, Kappa_] := 
 NIntegrate[a^-2 (E^(-1/a^2))*BesselI[0, 1/a^2], {a, 0.02, Kappa*t}]`? Then you can, for example, `Integralfunc[47, 23]` which gives `2.36619`. You can make a `Table` of the values or plot it with, e.g., `Plot3D[Evaluate@Integralfunc[t, k], {t, 0.1, 10}, {k, 1, 15}, 
 PlotRange -> All]`. Or, if you insist on a `Manipulate`: `Manipulate[Integralfunc[t, k], {t, 0.1, 250, 1.25}, {k, 1, 100}]`.

Comment: You are trying to numerically integrate to a variable, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually If I change the value of Kappa manually, than there is an answer for this problem, But I want to change Kappa like in Manipulate Function.

Comment: @AmanullahMalik corey's comment allows you to do that, then you can just run `Manipulate[Integralfunc[t, k], {t, 0.1, 10, 0.1}, {k, 1, 15}]`.

Comment: actually fact is for a certain value of kappa graph is in our favor it coulb be any value in an interva

Comment: The fast way to compute the same integral for different integration boundaries is to phrase it as a differential equation instead of an integral, and use `NDSolve`.  If $F(t) = \int_a^t f(x) dx$ then $F'(x) = f(x)$ and $F(a) = 0$, which is a differential equation with an initial condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClearAll[Integralfunc, DeFunc]
```

Functions that directly or indirectly use numeric techniques should have their arguments restricted to numeric values.

```
IntegralFunc[t_?NumericQ, Kappa_?NumericQ] :=

  NIntegrate[a^-2 (E^(-1/a^2))*BesselI[0, 1/a^2],
   {a, 0.02, Kappa*t}];

DeFunc[Kappa_?NumericQ] :=
 IntegralFunc[#, Kappa] & /@ Range[0.1, 250, 1.25]
```

Use a fixed `PlotRange` to make it easier to see the effect of changing `Kappa`

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[DeFunc[Kappa],
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotRange -> {2.3, 2.37}],
 {{Kappa, 5}, 1, 10, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]